# Reference a variable in a 2nd org-babel code block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, ess, r, literate-programming

How can I define vars in one org-babel code block and use them in a second?  This closely follows the tutorial section block-to-block 
variable passing linked in the first answer.

```
# file test.org
* try a session.
#+name: section1
#+begin_src R :results output both :session
x <- c(1:10)
y <- x^2
mat <- cbind(x,y)
mat
#+end_src 

#this is outputted into the MWE after you press C-c C-c
#+RESULTS: section1
#+begin_example
       x   y
 [1,]  1   1
 [2,]  2   4
 [3,]  3   9
 [4,]  4  16
 [5,]  5  25
 [6,]  6  36
 [7,]  7  49
 [8,]  8  64
 [9,]  9  81
[10,] 10 100
#+end_example



#+name: section2
#+BEGIN_SRC R :file example2.png :results graphics mat=section1
plot(mat)
#+END_SRC

#this is outputted into the MWE after you press C-c C-c
#+RESULTS: section2
here is a white box with the phrase
object 'mat' not found
when it is named section 2 the white box appears in the first results 
#+begin_example section and the matrix of numbers disappears.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* my.org

#+TITLE:TEST
#+AUTHOR:Benyomin
#+STARTUP: inlineimages

** This MWE graphs with a variable from an earlier code-block
#+begin_src R :results output :session
nums <- (seq(1,10))
nums
#+end_src

#+BEGIN_SRC R :file example.png :results graphics
plot(nums)
#+END_SRC
```

This is what happens after you hit C-c C-c both code blocks to execute the R code.
[image: MWE after code execution]

Answer (score 3):

A standard feature of babel blocks is each block is executed in a new interpreter. Often this is good as changes in one block doesn't mess up others.
I have two ideas for you...

In this particular case, you could break up the first block in two, so that the first block called the `c` function and spit out its results in a table that has the name, `<named_block>`. The other block would use that table output as a `:var` can call `summary` on it.

The third block would also set a `:var` and pass that to `mean`. That seems to me to be the most idiomatic approach. For details, see the [Variables section in my Literate Programming tutorial](http://howardism.org/Technical/Emacs/literate-programming-tutorial.html#sec-11).

Another approach is to set the `:session` parameter to some name, then each block that uses that same named session would share the same R interpreter, so setting variables in one block would then be accessible in the next. For details on this, see the [Session section](http://howardism.org/Technical/Emacs/literate-programming-tutorial.html#sec-8-3) in the same tutorial.

Good luck.